# Why do werewolves from Supernatural eat their victims hearts?

Tags: supernatural, werewolf

What is the lore and reason behind the writers decision that werewolves ate their victims hearts? Is this something in myth an legend or a new creation on top of what already exists?

Comment: I don't really know, but if someone wants to theorize, [Skinwalkers](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Skinwalkers) are basically the same - shift into dog form, infect with a bite, and eat the heart of their victims - but can shift at any time.  But [Shapeshifters](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Shapeshifters) don't eat hearts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the ways that Supernatural kept things familiar but strange was slightly twisting and combining the classic legends. They did this, I believe, to allow some surprises in for the horror aficionados, plus the added bonus of allowing them to say "Yeah, in Sam and Dean's world it works this way!"  I think that they added the heart part because there are quite a few werewolf movies from the Eighties in which the werewolf is seen biting into a heart that then spectacularly explodes. Also, if they failed to put in an easy calling card, a werewolf attack would look like any other wild animal attack and there would be a higher chance of viewer confusion.

Answer (score 2):

**Supernatural has always played fast and loose with ancient legends, magical beasts and mystical forces. While the show insists that werewolves devour the hearts of their prey, it does not mention why. I think we can reason our way to an answer, if we consider their behavior an amalgam of other legends and archetypes.**

- Werewolves feast on human hearts after they have changed into their beast form. This change is involuntary, but the need to feed on human hearts is an instinctive one not a reasoned one. Their prey is also savaged and partially eaten, as a rule.
- A Skinwalker is another animal shapeshifter with voluntary control of their shapechanging ability that has similar dining habits. Since they have more control, they may choose to change their shape AND may need human hearts to continue to exist.
- Supernatural also has another creature called a lamia that prefers to feast specifically on human hearts as well. In legends, she was a woman cursed and in a fashion similar to a vampire or succubus fed on human flesh, blood and spiritual essence.
- Since all of these are conditions are curses, they may require the curse sufferer to both take the life of another human AND consume their heart as a condition of the curse.
- There are other human legends and events (not from the Supernatural TV series) where the consumption of the heart was reputed to benefit the eater. These were all real.

  - The Iroquois were known for doing this with their more respected enemies. They believed it conferred the strength, stamina and the warrior essence of the consumed.
  - In Bolivia, the native peoples celebrated their victories over the Spanish by feasting on their hearts after great battles.
  - The Aztecs were known to sacrifice their enemies by removing their hearts and offering them to the gods. The priests would consume the hearts in proxy.
  - Tribes in South Africa believed the consumption of the heart of their enemies would confer magical strength and power to the consumer.
- It is likely images like these were the inspiration for Supernatural's heart-chewing fiends. Cannibalism is one of the only human taboos left on the books, and cultures that violated that taboo were rare and often considered a bit beyond the pale for others that didn't.

In Supernatural, monster cultures are centralized about the consumption of human flesh, blood, spiritual essence, psychic powers or even the very soul of humans. This is exactly what makes them so monstrous to us. It isn't just that they feed on humanity, we believe ourselves to be the Alpha predator at the top of the food chain.

On this show, Humanity is just another link in a much longer, faster, more dangerous, more ferocious food chain and we are the slowest thing on the menu.

Comment: Which of those bullet points are stories/legends and which are specifically from Supernatural?